# Unknown domain names pointing to my site

Tags: apache, namespaces, dedicated

I just recently to see that many domain name (Polish, etc.) point to my dedicated server. It's by making a whois you can see that these areas are on the same IP as mine and on the same host.

I would like to avoid it and to authorize only mydomainname.com to connect to my site (I use Apache).

Thank you for your help

A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of defense for unwanted traffic is IP filtering using a firewall.  In your case, I believe you want to use mod_access which has an allow|deny by domain.

.htaccess

```
Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from mydomainname.com
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html

Comment: Ok, so I will use a firewall. Thanks.

Comment: A firewall will usually not be able to do this. It needs to be done on layer 5. It's much easier to just configure your web server to treat *unknown* hostnames ("named virtual hosts") with a **redirect** to `wikipedia.org`

Comment: Sorry... I wasn't thinking in terms of hostnames on the same machine, but forwarding all traffic to other servers you do not own is irresponsible. For example, what if someone decided to start a DOS attack on my server? I would then be redirecting the DOS attack on whomever I decided to redirect all my traffic to.

Comment: A DOS tool will usually ignore the response (just firing out requests as fast as possible) and not follow the redirect Anyway, the filter you proposed is a **source** filter. So it will only accept internal requests (even when they go the wrong domain), reject outside visitors. Probably not what he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you configure a "Name based virtual host" that will point your domain at your site, and point any others to a small application that serves up a "Invalid domain" page.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: Blindly forwarding all traffic to other servers you do not own is irresponsible. For example, what if someone decided to start a DOS attack on my server? I would then be redirecting the DOS attack on whoever I decided to redirect all my traffic to.  It's Better to stop unwanted traffic, then force it upon someone else.

Comment: That's a valid point.  I was assuming the incoming traffic would be genuine mistakes.  I have edited the answer to correct this.

Comment: What do you think about a redirect to 127.0.0.1 ?